# Two-way Google Photos sync as folders of files on desktop

Tags: file-synchronization, google-apps, synchronization, google-drive

The Google Photos app on my phone automatically uploads *every* photo to the server, 90% of which are junk and take up my Google Drive storage space.

I would like a way to synchronize my Google Photos with my desktop computer as actual files on the filesystem.

I want to be able to view them in native resolution and quickly go through duplicates and delete the blurry ones, and have them removed from Google Photos (and from my Google Drive storage quota).

Comment: It's been a while since I used Google Photos, but I thought their own sync tool does that. Can you explain why the [Google Drive for Desktop](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) tool isn't suitable?

Comment: In the past, I used [odrive](https://odrive.com), which supports Google Drive, but I'm unsure about Photos. Maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: @Lockszmith The current Google Drive software has options for *uploading* to Google Photos from phones when plugged in, but it doesn't download or sync that I'm aware of. odrive lists Google Drive, but not Google Photos.